# Generate data from a t-distribution with specified mean and standard deviation

Tags: r, distributions, random-generation, t-distribution, non-central

How does one randomly sample from a T-distribution in R. From what I've found, the function `rt` in R doesn't let you specify the mean and standard deviation. For a normal distribution it is simply `rnorm(x,mu,sd)`.

EDIT:

For the t-distribution there is a *central* and a *non-central* version. I want to know the difference between the two.  In addition, if I want to specify the mean and standard deviation, does that automatically mean I am dealing with the non-central version of the t-distribution?

I chose to use the t-distribution because the data I am using are rather fat tailed and a t-distribution with a low degrees of freedom seems like a good idea. What other distributions are there for handling fat tailed data? Also it would be great if you can specify the function in R too.

Comment: This question appears to be what you are after. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843497/sampling-from-a-t-distribution-in-r

Comment: Thanks perfect! I was wondering how would a non central vs a central t affects my sampling?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is only about how to use R.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using/finding a function in R. There is an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843497/sampling-from-a-t-distribution-in-r

Comment: I think this question is subtly on-topic. I don't think the real issue is 'what R function...' or 'how do I use the R function...'. The problem seems to be a confusion about what t-distributions *are* & how they are similar to / different from normal distributions. In addition, "how would a non central vs a central t affects [sic] my sampling?" is clearly on-topic.

Comment: I just editted my question to reflect my real question thanks gung

Comment: Please tell us *how* you plan to use these distributions in your data analysis.  (A great many people come here with questions about distributions that are motivated by misconceptions about the underlying assumptions of their analyses, so we might as well get that cleared up at the outset.)

Comment: My underlying data is stocks. Stocks tend to have a fat distribution, so I wanted to use the t-distribution to generate some data to mimic the distribution of stocks.

Comment: So i would take the mean and standard deviation of the stock and plug it in to the t-distribution sampling function `rt` with say degrees of freedom of 3.

Comment: A starting place: [Noncentral t](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution) vs [ordinary t](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution)

Comment: A t distribution is interesting because it has inverse power tails.  What analyses have you run to determine that your stocks (presumably their *relative changes* in price and not the prices themselves) actually do appear to have such tails?  How have you determined the rate of decrease of the tails?